# No keyword with name &{headers}= Create Dictionary found in robot

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

When I run this test (which is to test login page in a website, I get "No keyword with name &{headers}= Create Dictionary found". How can I make this test run correctly?

I've previously installed all the imported libraries, and I've used them in other tests so I know they've been installed correctly.

```
*** Settings ***
Library     Collections
Library     RequestsLibrary
Library     OperatingSystem
*** Variables ***
${authToken}   
${username} example.user@email.com
${password} password
*** Test Cases ***
Log in Dashboard
    &{data}=    Create Dictionary   email=${username}   password=${password}
    &{headers}= Create Dictionary   Accept=application/json, text/plain, */*    Content-Type=application/json   Origin=http://examplesite.com   Referer=http://examplesite.com/angular/
    Create session  example   http://examplesite.com
    ${response}=    Post Request    example   /admin/login data=${data}    headers=${headers}
    log ${response}
    log ${response.json()}
    ${allocation_response}= To Json ${response.content}
    Set Global  Variable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly your IDE was too "smart" and even though you hit TAB it only inserted one SPACE here:

```
&{headers}= Create Dictionary   Accept=application/json, text/plain, */*    Content-Type=application/json   Origin=http://examplesite.com   Referer=http://examplesite.com/angular/
```

you seem to have only one space between the variable and the keyword thus it is considered as one keyword. Add more SPACE there to fix it.

```
&{headers}=    Create Dictionary   Accept=application/json, text/plain, */*    Content-Type=application/json   Origin=http://examplesite.com   Referer=http://examplesite.com/angular/
```

Possibly you will have the same problem at this line as well:

```
${allocation_response}= To Json ${response.content}
```